# Changing image src from anchor onclick using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, image, onclick, anchor

I'm using jquery to pop up an AddThis share box when I click on a link that surrounds an image.  It works great. The jquery code I'm using is here:

```
        //added to show/hide add-this
    $('a#slick-toggle').click(function() {
        $('#atBox').toggle(100);
        return false;
    });
```

And this is my relevant html:

```
<a id="slick-toggle" href="#" title="Share">
<img src="images/navicon/navicon4_off.gif" alt="share" id="share" class="img-swap">
</a>
```

This makes a little div box appear that has some sharing icons. It's working as intended.

What I wanted to do was also make the image that is inside the anchor tags "switch" when the anchor tag was clicked on. Unfortunately the regular jquery image "onclick" scripts I found for doing that don't seem to work, presumably because the "link" is being clicked, not the image? Anyway, I tried "merging" the initial script with an image swapping script by doing the following, but no luck:

```
     $('a#slick-toggle').click(function() {

        if ($('#share').attr("class") == "img-swap") {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_off","_on");
        } else {
            this.src = this.src.replace("_on","_off");
        }
        $('.img-swap').toggleClass("on");


        $('#atBox').toggle(100);
        return false;
    });
```

It doesn't seem to matter what I put in that third line, I can't ever get the jquery to recognize that I'm referring to the image.  I keep getting a "Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined" message. I've tried this, $('#share') and ('#share'), and they all give me the same message.  I'm not too familiar with jquery but am I doing something obviously wrong in my script to refer to the image tag when the function is being called on the anchor onclick event?

Thanks!

Comment: just of note <img src="..." ...>  is not valid html.  It should be <img src="..." ... />  You should always remember to close your image tags.

Comment: @John - that depends on your DOCTYPE.

Comment: Thanks for the tip :) I actually had the closing tag but it got lost during the code tidying I did when I posted so people didn't have to look at a bunch of superfluous stuff ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the image inside since your `click` handler is on the `<a>` that wraps it, like this:

```
$('a#slick-toggle').click(function() {
  var img = $(this).find("img")[0];
    if ($('#share').attr("class") == "img-swap") {
        img.src = img.src.replace("_off","_on");
    } else {
        img.src = img.src.replace("_on","_off");
    }
    $('.img-swap').toggleClass("on");
    $('#atBox').toggle(100);
    return false;
});
```

Or, switch things up a bit like this:

```
$('a#slick-toggle').click(function() {
  var img = $('#share')[0], isSwap = img.className == "img-swap";
  img.src = isSwap ? img.src.replace("_off","_on") : img.src.replace("_on","_off");
  $('.img-swap').toggleClass("on");
  $('#atBox').toggle(100);
  return false;
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks very much for the super-quick help! :D

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative: try using .children() to select a child element of the current one you've clicked

```
$(this).children('> img')
```

In that case, the image that is a direct descendant of where the click function is called.

http://api.jquery.com/children/